# add a leading zero case when

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, case-when

I am trying to add a leading zero to a week number if it's less than 10. Both col types are smallint and I've tried the following code which is not producing what I want. what I get:'20201' vs what I want '202001'.

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(yr_num AS VARCHAR), CASE WHEN CAST(wk_num AS VARCHAR) < 10 THEN '0' + wk_num ELSE wk_num  END) as year_wk FROM sometable
```

I am using redshift for this query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `lpad()`:

```
select concat(yr_num, lpad(wk_num, 2, '0'))
```

I don't think you need to convert the numbers for `concat()`, but I don't have Redshift on-hand to test.